# Pin bootstrap col-md-2 div to the top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to have my bootstrap 3.0 layout pin the content of the right column to the top, thus staying in place as the main content scrolls on.  I have arrived at the following code, which blows up as I re-size the browser.  Is there a way to do this?

```
    <div class="col-md-10>main content</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 container" style="padding: 15px 0px 10px 23px; position: fixed; right: 20px; top:75px">
        Right column, stuck to the top
    </div>
```

I am not really (engineer learning these techniques) a bootstrap or CSS guy, so if bootstrap doesn't support this - that is valuable information for me as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `affix` on the content inside the right column..

```
  <div class="col-md-10>main content</div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="affix">..</div>
  </div>
```

Here's an example Bootply that you may find useful: http://bootply.com/104413

Answer (score 2):

### [Demo](http://bootply.com/73866)

You can do this by using the `affix` class.

```
<div class="well col-span-4" data-spy="affix">
    <div class="btn btn-large btn-danger col-span-12">This is fixed</div>
</div>
```

### Animation

[image]